# Change log entry pattern dynamically on some condition

Tags: java, logback

In my Java app Logback is used as logging framework. The appenders configured with the following pattern (simplified):

```
[CORR=%X{CORR}] [MSG=%msg]%n
```

As one can see, `CORR` value is taken from `MDC`. Log entry example:

```
[CORR=12342314] [MSG=Some message]
```

There are cases when the attribute is not stored in `MDC`, so log entry looks like:

```
[CORR=] [MSG=Some message]
```

But should be:

```
[MSG=Some message]
```

Is there any way to totally get rid of this `[CORR=]` part of pattern if the corresponding value is absent in `MDC` without creating custom `LayoutBase` implementations?
I'm trying to configure evaluator:

```
<evaluator name="DISPLAY_CORR_EVAL">
    <expression>((String) mdc.get("CORR")) != null</expression>
</evaluator>
```

but have no idea how to use it in my case.

Comment: With a custom layout that should be possible, see http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html

Comment: Found solutions without custom layout.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem was solved with help of Logback `replace(p){r, t}` conversion word:

> Replaces occurrences of 'r', a regex, with its replacement 't' in the
>   string produces by the sub-pattern 'p'. For example,
>   "%replace(%msg){'\s', ''}" will remove all spaces contained in the
>   event message.
>
> The pattern 'p' can be arbitrarily complex and in particular can
>   contain multiple conversion keywords. For instance, "%replace(%logger
>   %msg){'.', '/'}" will replace all dots in the logger or the message
>   of the event with a forward slash.

My pattern now looks as follows:

```
%replace([CORR=%X{CORR}]){'\[CORR=\]', ''}[MSG=]%n
```

when `CORR` is empty, `[CORR=]` matches `r` regex and thus being replaced by empty string.